# how do i pick a memory in an array that i create after displaying the array value. how to slect thte value with cin when the program run

Tags: arrays

```
string bookname [5] = {"STPM BOOKS","SPM BOOKS","PMR BOOKS","TEXT BOOK","PRACTICAL BOOK"};
 float  price [5] = {30.90,24.90,19.90,45.90,15.90};


        for(int i = 0; i < 5 ; i++)
        {
            cout << i+1 << "book name " << bookname[i] << " ---- RM " << price[i] << endl;}
```

i want to select the value for example like stpm books and its price from the array and display it to cout after selecting from a cin and doing the selection when the code was excercuted

}

Comment: its for C++ programming

Answer (score 0):

Based on your updated query, asking for an exit condition, I have modified the code.  Please note that I have used `getline(cin, answer)` to handle the input.  I use getline() because I am less likely to mess up when I use `getline()` over `cin >> answer`.

> Note that getline(cin, answer) does a few things for you:
>
> - Returns true if input was received
> - Fills in the answer
> - Gets an entire line, until user provides new line

Thus, the line `while (std::getline(std::cin, answer) && answer != "n")` will get an entire book, even if there are spaces.  The && allows for a check of the answer for "n" before entering the while loop's body.
As answer is a `std::string`, the comparison is to `"n"`, not `'n'`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip> // setprecision

int main()
{

  std::string bookname[5] =
      {"STPM BOOKS", "SPM BOOKS", "PMR BOOKS", "TEXT BOOK", "PRACTICAL BOOK"};

  float price[5] = {30.90, 24.90, 19.90, 45.90, 15.90};

  std::string answer;
  float cost;

  std::cout << "Please provide the name of a book or type 'n' to exit"
            << std::endl;
  // get one line into answer, and also exit while if answer is "n"
  while (std::getline(std::cin, answer) && answer != "n") {  
    bool found = false;
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
      if (bookname[i] == answer) {
        std::cout << "The book " << bookname[i] << " costs $" << std::fixed
                  << std::setprecision(2) << price[i] << std::endl;
        found = true;
        break; // /no need to continue inside the for loop
      }
    }

    // on last loop, give up
    if (!found) {
      std::cout << "The book " << answer << " is not in our inventory"
                << std::endl;
    }
  }

}
```

Comment: now i am facing a problem where the array manage to input but now i want to put it into the while loop    while (answer != 'n') i want to keep looping the array and then dis continue it but the problem now is any data type that i mix in that function with this array will not show anything when run and ask me to press anything to exit the program.

Comment: You have done a great job so far.  When you use a `while (answer !='n')`, you are creating an exit condition.  Please provide the code that is "will not show anything when run".